# Type initializer threw exception while accessing static property

Tags: c#, exception, static

I have the following static property defined:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        private static byte[] aes256Key = null;
        internal static byte[] Aes256Key
        {
            get
            {
                if (aes256Key != null)
                {
                    return aes256Key;
                }

                aes256Key = new byte[32];

                // Fill in key...

                return aes256Key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In another class within an internal namespace, I am accessing this property:

```
namespace Foo.Cryptography
{
    public class SymmetricCryptography
    {
        internal static void EncryptFile(
            string sourceFile,
            string destinationFile)
        {
            // <snip>
            AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.Key = Bar.Aes256Key; // Accessing the key here
            // <snip>
        }
    }
}
```

`Foo.Cryptography` is used by an executable console application.  When I run this console application manually from my build environment, I don't see any issues.  However, when the executable is run within the context of the build process (on a server with a potentially different environment), I see the following runtime exception:

```
The type initializer for 'Foo.Bar' threw an exception.
```

The executable project in VS2008 has a reference to the `Foo` project which defines the `Foo` namespace.

Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong here?  What could be causing this?

Comment: Type initializers are great and I love using them as much as the next guy, but I've gotten away from using them for anything but the absolute simplest stuff because they don't give you very good feedback when they blow up.  If the exception hadn't been in the type initializer you'd probably have gotten an actually useful message back.

Comment: I would say to take any Type Initializer code and defer it until after the type has been initialized so you can get a better error message, but it really doesn't look like there's much of anything going on in the Type Initializer judging by the code you've supplied.

Comment: In the posted code there is no type initializer. There are no fields that needs initialization, and no static type initializer is shown in the code. As such, nobody here can answer why the code fails because you haven't posted that code. Please post the rest of your field declarations and if you have it, your static type initializer.

Comment: @Lasse - thanks for your comment.  I am fairly new to C# - isn't the `aes256Key` member using a static type initializer?  If not, can you give an example of what one may look like?

Comment: Example: private static byte[] aes256Key = new byte[256];`, the important part is the `new byte[256]`, this will be executed as part of type initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to work on 'static world' without seeing the complete code. Nonetheless, following are few area that you can work on (personally) in order to find the cause.

```
aes256Key = new byte[32];
// Fill in key...
return aes256Key;
```

1. It's reasonable to check the possible exception in your 'Fill in key' logic
2. Define a static constructor for this Bar and initialize all your static fields.
3. Ensure you call following `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Bar).TypeHandle)`
                    before even accessing any `static/instance field/member/method`.

   `static void Main(string[] args)`

   {

   ```
   RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Bar).TypeHandle);
   byte[] bt = Bar.Aes256Key;
   ```

   }

RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor does ask the runtime to call the static constructor regardless of the reasons specified in the CLI. This ensure deterministic unit initialization order. This is necessary because type initializer believe in Lazy initialization.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on or use `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor` in anything but special-case code.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.Aes256Key` won't even compile, because `Foo` is your namespace...

Comment: Sorry, corrected the code.  It does compile, I just changed the names of the namespaces/classes (a bit incorrectly, it seems) when submitting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are Foo.Cryptography and Foo.Bar in the same dll?  Sounds like a dependency problem like it just can't find the dll on the hard drive that contains Foo.Bar.

Edit: Okay the above is obviously not the problem...

Probably a class you're using in the initializer requires a dependency that's not on the production machine... I don't see anything in your code but maybe it's in the part you left out.  I would assume you have the full .net framework loaded on the production machine.  Are you using any objects in the part of the code you left out that would directly or indirectly call code from any other in house or 3rd party dlls?

Another Edit: Actually I don't think code in the part you left out would be able to cause this error because it shouldn't run automatically when the class initializes.  Are you sure there's not any other code you're leaving out?  I don't see anything here that looks like it could cause that kind of exception.

It looks like "private static byte[] aes256Key = null;" is the only line even capable of causing this exception, but I think it's pretty clear that this line is not going to do that.

Comment: If they're in different dll's, try manually checking that the dll containing Foo.Bar is located in the same directory as the dll containing Foo.Cryptography (if that's not the same as the application directory, then try making sure it's available there too).  If that fixes your error then you know you just have a problem in your distribution.

Comment: Thanks, but they are in the same DLL.

Comment: Oops, just realized I wasn't thinking totally straight... it's obviously finding Foo.Bar because it can get to its Type Initializer in the first place.  I'll update my answer to something hopefuly more useful...